# Leer fichero acces estando éste en otro ordenador

Tags: base-de-datos, vba, redes

Estoy leyendo un fichero acces desde VBA en Excel, si ambos están en el mismo ordenador no hay problema.

Pero si el fichero *Acces* esta en otro ordenador, conectados por Ethernet y como *Workgroup*, no lo consigo.

El código que funciona, es:

```
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

MiConexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\__TENDA\__JULIOL\MERCE_JULIOL_1\EXECEL_ACCES\dbase_210730_0001.mdb"

With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MiConexion
End With

consultaSql = "Select * from tickets;"
'Conn.Open MiConexion ' l'objecte ja es obert

Set datos = Conn.Execute(consultaSql)
```

Cuando quiero conectar con otro ordenador por ethernet, escribo:

```
MiConexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=\\PCmiki\C:\dbase_210730_0001.mdb"
```

Ya que tengo el fichero *Acces* en *C* del ordenador PCmiki...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿realizaste la prueba con la respuesta? Por favor, finaliza la pregunta si así lo consideras.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no tengas permisos hacia la unidad y menos a la raiz del disco c:
Prueba a montar un volumen hacia el pcMiki y después realizar la conexión a:

```
MiConexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=Z:\dbase_210730_0001.mdb"
```